# One To Many with pivot not possible. How to redesign relationships?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

I would like to do the following:

**Product** can have one **Supplier**. The **Supplier** contains some data like a `name`. Additionally there is a pivot-value that should be stored for **Supplier** that is assigned to **Product** (e.g. a `delivery_service`-string).

### Example:

- **Product**: A yummy Banana
- **Supplier**: Banana Inc

-> If the **Product** "A yummy Banana" is supplied by **Supplier** it should be delivered by *DHL*. The important thing: You can not add *DHL* as a field to **Supplier**, as each Product to Supplier-relation should have it's own delivery-service-field.

As there can be many **Product**s  but each **Product** can only have one **Supplier** I thought about something like this:

**Product**

*Schema*:

```
- id
- supplier_id
```

*Relation*

```
public function supplier()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Supplier::class);
}
```

**Supplier**

*Schema*:

```
- id
- name
```

*Relation*

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
}
```

This works, but unfortunately I can not store pivot data in the `supplier()` relation.

At the moment I could imagine to store the `value` not in a pivot table but in a new `row` in the **Product**'s schema. But I don't think this is the best way.

Any suggestions? :-)

Comment: Can you tell what are these models? It's hard to advice when you're being so vague. Also, there's no such thing as pivot table in one-to-many relationship.

Comment: I updated the question and added the real-life-purpose :-)

Comment: What is an exaple data for delivery service? What is it used for?

Comment: I updated my question, see section "Example":  If the Product "A yummy Banana" is supplied by Supplier it should be delivered by DHL. The important thing: You can not add DHL as a field to Supplier, as each Product to Supplier-relation should have it's own delivery-service-field.

Comment: Why can't you just store your delivery data in products table if that's always the only one? To be honest, I think you should define this as many to many relation with some flag of current supplier. I don't believe there will always be only one supplier per product, without ever switching to another one.

Answer (score 0):

One **item** have many **childs**
This is one-to-many

You need to store item_id in your child table

```php
Item Table
id, name
```

```php
Child Table
id, item_id, type
```

If you have a case EG
Each child can have a favorite item then you will have to create a many-to-many relation between them. *(Which will be a separate relation)*

Create a table "child_item" (pivot)

```php
Child Item Table
child_id, item_id
```

then create a relation in your laravel

```php
class User extends Model{
   ...

   public function favorites(){
      return $this->belongsToMany(Items::class); // Include the path using "use" on top
   }


}
```

So now you get your 2 relations between child and item

1. One item can have many children
2. Many children can mark items as favorites

Comment: Hi and thank you for your answer. But in this case, one item can only have one child.